# Oauth requests inside Webview

Tags: android, webview, oauth

Google has blocked oauth requests inside webviews. But I need this facility. Is there any way to do this or anyone has done it using some alternative method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView has a default user agent that identifies itself to the internet as being a WebView. 
The trick is to set a user agent for the webview that matches Chrome Browser user agent or another browser.

```
 public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; Nexus 6 Build/N6F27M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.84 Mobile Safari/537.36";
 webview.getSettings().setUserAgent(USER_AGENT)
```

You can load this website to check your user agent.
https://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/

Hope this helps!